# Mongoose, update values in array of objects for specific filter condition

Tags: mongoose, typegoose

I'am having issues updating a document with an array of objects, I'm using typegoose to define schemas and models and I only want to update a specific value from the array of objetcs. Here is the code. WHen I try to update the array of LastOpenedUserEntity under a specific user_id the date is not updating to Date.now(). I'm using with schemas:

```
export class LastOpenedUserEntity {
    @prop()
    public date: Date;

    @prop()
    public user: number;
}

export class ReportEntity {
    public _id: ObjectId;

    @prop()
    public name: string;

    @prop()
    public owner_id: number;

    @prop({ type: () => [Number] })
    public editor: number[];

    @prop({ default: Date.now })
    public creation_date: Date;

    @prop({ default: [], type: () => [Number] })
    public users_favorited: number[];

    @prop({ default: false, type: () => [Boolean] })
    public deleted: boolean;

    @prop({ default: [], type: () => [AdCardEntity] })
    public adcard_set: AdCardEntity[];

    @prop({ default: [], type: () => LastOpenedUserEntity })
    public last_opened_users: LastOpenedUserEntity[];

    @prop({ default: [], ref: () => VisualizationEntity, type: () => VisualizationEntity })
    public visualization: VisualizationEntity[];
}

export const ReportModel = getModelForClass(ReportEntity);
```

This is how I am trying to update the specific value:

```
export const updateLastOpened = async (report: ReportEntity, user_id: number): Promise<void> => {
    try {

ReportModel.updateOne(
                {
                    _id: report._id,
                    'last_opened_users.user': user_id,
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        'last_opened_users.$.date': new Date(),
                    },
                },
                {
                    safe: true,
                }
            );
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};
```

I want to update the date given a specific user_id

Comment: Please add a short explanation what actually doesn't work!

Comment: I just updated to question but basically when I call this method mongoose is not updating the value under a report_id found  and user_id found, I want to update the value for last_opened_user[user_id].date

Comment: I think you maybe be searching for `$[<identifier>]`, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#mongodb-update-up.---identifier--